# How to display text without HTML tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in MVC 2 application, and i want to display the text from the editor without HTML tags, like bellow

Text in editor:`<p>Some text</p>`
Text to display: `Some text`

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

How about using `HTML Agility Pack` and strip all HTML tags in the controller `action` method and output the result tot he view ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open the document in `Preview` mode.

**Reference**: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Document/Preview

Comment: Preview is a command of the editor, you don't want your end users to load the editor just to click then on the Preview button.